# Is the Galois group associated to a random polynomial solvable with probability 0?

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, galois-theory, math-history, solvable-groups

Choose a random polynomial $P\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $n$ and coefficients $\leq n$ and $\geq-n$.

Let $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ be the roots of $P$ and consider $$G=\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(r_1,\ldots,r_n)/\mathbb{Q})$$

What is the probability, as $n\to\infty,$ that $G$ is solvable? (I assume 0.) Who first proved this?

Comment: I remember reading that $G$ was a symmetric group with probability $1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.  I will try to find a reference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

$G\cong S_n$ with probability $1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.  This was proven first by

B. L. van der Waerden, [Die Seltenheit der Gleichungen mit Affekt](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002276607), *Mathematische Annalen* **109**:1 (1934), pp. 13–16.

Look at [this](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=1676779) thread for more references.

Comment: For further work on this (getting error estimates on how close the probability is to 1 in a large box), look at Theorem 1.6 and the paragraph following it in www.technion.ac.il/~weiss/Distn-v56.pdf.

Comment: @KCd I cannot find the Weiss reference anymore (not even ~weiss at the technion. Any thoughts?

Comment: @IgorRivin: The author is Benjamin Weiss, who is at Bates now. The comment I made above was written about a year ago, and I don't know what "v56" in the URL could mean anymore, but the broken link most likely went to the paper "Probabilistic Galois of p-adic Fields", which appears now in Journal of Number Theory 133 (2013), 1537--1563. See Theorem 2.11 and the paragraph following it.

Comment: @KCd thanks! I am writing a survey on related matters, so this is helpful...

Comment: Let me put here what Weiss describes in van der Waerden's theorem and some later work. For any positive integer $B$, let $F_{n,B}$ be the set of monic, degree $n$ polynomials in
$\mathbf Z[x]$ with all coeﬃcients in $[−B + 1, B]$ and $P_n(B)$ be the proportion of polynomials in $F_{n,B}$ that are irreducible over $\mathbf Q$ and have Galois group $S_n$. Then $1− P_n(B) \ll B^{−c/\log\log B}$ as $B → \infty$, where $c = 1/(6(n-2))$. I guess $n \geq 3$. Later the error bound on $1 - P_n(B)$ was improved to $O((\log B)/\sqrt{B})$ (Gallagher) and $O_t(1/B^{t})$ for any $t < 2-\sqrt{2}$ (Dietmann).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the probability is zero since it equals the symmetric group with probability one:

If $Q_d(N)$ denotes the set of degree $d$ polynomials with coefficients $|a_i|\le N$ with Galois group not equal to $S_d$, then
$$
|Q_d(N)|\ll N^{d-1/2}\log N
$$

This bound is sufficient to prove your result. This was proven by Patrick X. Gallagher.

EDIT: Gallagher proved the following stronger result:

$$|Q_d(N)| \ll N^{d-1/2} \log^{1 - \gamma} N$$

where $\gamma \sim (2 \pi d)^{-1/2}$. [Source](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/pdf/332694.pdf?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=Gallagher%2C%20P%20%2A&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=22)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a citation?

Comment: @Charles Let me try and find it. I'll get back to you when I do.

Comment: Thanks! Mathscinet has 20 references but none of them obvious to me.

Comment: @Charles I have updated the answer with an improved bound and a source for that.