# When are the eigenvalues of a matrix containing all squared elements irrational/rational?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory

Forgive me in advance if any of this is trivial. After looking at many `2x2` matrices it seems that if all of the elements in matrix are unique squared integers then the eigenvalues are irrational. So I tried to investigate this:

$\det \begin{pmatrix} \lambda -a^2 & b^2\\ c^2& \lambda -d^2\end{pmatrix}= \lambda^2 -(a^2+d^2)\lambda + (a^2d^2-c^2b^2)$

after applying the quadratic formula this gives a radical of,

$\sqrt{a^4+4b^2c^2-2a^2d^2+d^4}$

If the stated observation is true, is there a way to show that this is irrational? Furthermore it looks like on the surface that for `3x3` matrices the eigenvalues for a matrix containing all  unique squared entries that the eigenvalues will also be irrational. Are either of these statements true? Is there a generalization of this for an `nxn` matrix?

Edit: I'm not entirely sure I derived the radical correctly, but I'd still like to have some direction on the questions above also **I'd like to examine cases where the eigenvalue is not zero**

Example: 
\begin{pmatrix}
2^2 & 4^2\\ 
3^2 & 6^2
\end{pmatrix}
has eigenvalues 40 and 0.

**Edit 2: still looking for rational eigenvalues of a $3x3$ have been with imposed restrictions and nonzero eigenvalues/entries.**

Comment: The matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
5^2 & 2^2\\ 
7^2 & 3^2
\end{pmatrix}$ has as eigenvalues $17\pm 2\sqrt{65}$

Comment: The radical should be $\sqrt{a^4 + 4 b^2 c^2 - 2 a^2 d^2 + d^4}$.

Comment: Does this all look correct now? Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @SebastianCor is $\sqrt{65}$ rational?

Comment: $\sqrt{65}$ is not rational

Comment: In the first display equation, I think you mean for all of $a^2, b^2, c^2, d^2$ to have the same sign.

Comment: Also, since the characteristic polynomial of a matrix is monic, any rational eigenvalues of such matrices (or any matrices with integer entries) in fact must be integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is not true. The matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}1^2&36^2\\5^2&26^2\end{bmatrix}$$
has eigenvalues $721$ and $-44$, which are evidently rational.

Comment: Thanks! So I presume then there are probably 3x3 matrices that have irrational eigenvectors? Are they just really difficult to find? (is there a reason they are abundant in $3x3$ but hard to find in $2x2$?

Comment: @user709560 Yes, probably. I don't know of such an example though, maybe I'll try and find one later.

Comment: That would be very much appreciated. I knew the claim seemed kind of ridiculous but I just could not find counter examples.

Comment: How did you find that, out of interest?

Comment: @Time4Tea I simply asked Mathematica to find instances where the radical (in the question body) is equals to an integer, and $a,b,c,d$ are distinct. It returned the answer quite quickly.

Comment: Ah, ok. Nice effort :)

Comment: Haha I just found it while I was studying these matrices, I made the observation and then started trying to figure out why and couldn't find an explanation. Also I'm looking now to see if there is one with non-negative values? It seems there is probably some reason for why this happens too which I'd like to investigate. And if this occurs under a special condition.

Comment: @YiFan good idea

Comment: Here is another with non-negative eigenvalues and no ones,    $ \begin{pmatrix}
14^2 & 36^2 \\ 
 5^2 & 26^2 
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @user709560 nice! Did you find that by hand?

Comment: Playing around on Desmos, maybe they are not as hard to find now that there is a way to look for them.

Comment: Also I'm trying to find a similar radical for the 3x3 case but there is a lot of algebra involved. (I make mistakes a lot)

Comment: Do you know anywhere online where it has already derived?

Comment: @user709560 I know no such online resource, no. It's quite unlikely that you can find somewhere which addresses this exact problem either. BTW, if you are willing to spend the time and effort I strongly recommend learning how to use Mathematica (it's been released for free just recently): it can do all the tedious algebra for you, calculate the eigenvalues and much much more.

Comment: I will definitely look into that thanks

Comment: @YiFan Is this example minimal in any sense, e.g., minimizing $|a| + |b| + |c| + |d|$ or $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$?

Comment: @Travis This is the smallest example I found so far, $\begin{pmatrix}
2^2 & 4^2\\ 
3^2 & 7^2
\end{pmatrix}$ gives 51 and 1 eigenvalues

Comment: @Travis No, I don't think so. I did not take into account such a minimality condition when asking Mathematica to find the example.

Comment: @user709560 I found a few solutions that are "smaller" in some senses. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If $b = 0$ or $c = 0$, then the matrix is triangular and so the eigenvalues are just the diagonal entries $a^2, d^2$ (which in particular are rational). So, any of the $12$ choices with $\{a, b, c, d\} = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ and either $b = 0$ or $c = 0$ gives a solution, and these examples evidently minimize $\max\{a, b, c, d\}$ among nonnegative solutions.

If we exclude $0 \in \{a, b, c, d\}$ to avoid these trivial solutions, the minimal solutions and their eigenvalues are \begin{array}{cc}\hline (a, b, c, d) & \lambda \\ \hline(1, 2, 5, 4) & -4, 21 \\ (4, 2, 3, 5) & 13, 28 \\ \hline \end{array} and the six examples obtained from these using the evident symmetries $a \leftrightarrow d$ and $b \leftrightarrow c$.

For the $3 \times 3$ case already the matrix $$\pmatrix{0^2 & 1^2 & 2^2 \\ 3^2 & 4^2 & 5^2 \\ 6^2 & 7^2 & 8^2}$$ has irrational eigenvalues: Its characteristic polynomial, $c(t) = t^3 - 80 t^2 - 354 t + 216$, has positive discriminant, so it has three real roots. On the other hand, $c(t) \equiv t^3 + t + 1 \pmod 5$, but this latter polynomial has no roots modulo $5$, hence $c(t)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, that is, its three real roots are irrational.

In a sense that can be made precise, most rational polynomials do not have all roots rational, and I see little reason to expect that the characteristic polynomials of matrices with (distinct) square entries would be special in this regard, so it is perhaps more interesting to ask for an example whose eigenvalues *are* rational (and hence integral). A quick Maple script (transcribed below) finds many examples with entries $0^2, \ldots, 8^2$. The first of these lexicographically is
$$\pmatrix{0^2 & 2^2 & 3^2 \\ 5^2 & 8^2 & 1^2 \\ 7^2 & 6^2 & 4^2} , \quad
\textrm{which has eigenvalues} \quad {-13}, 24, 69 .$$
It is rare even among the matrices with entries $0^2, \ldots, 8^2$ to have all rational eigenvalues: It only happens for $252$ of the $9! = 362880$ cases, $180$ of which have no zero eigenvalues.

```
restart;
with(combinat): with(LinearAlgebra):
m := 3;
N := 9;

for numberSet in choose(N, m^2) do
    shifted := map(U -> U - 1, numberSet);
    print([shifted]);
    for ordering in permute(shifted) do
        map(U -> U^2, ordering);
        A := convert([seq(%[((i - 1) * m + 1)..(i * m)], i=1..m)], Matrix);
        c := CharacteristicPolynomial(A, t);
        if (convert(map(degree, map(U -> U[1], factors(c)[2]), t), set) = {1}) then
            print(ordering, A, solve(c));
        fi:
    od:
od:
```

Here the constant $m$ is the matrix size, $[0, \ldots, N - 1]$ is the range from which the squared numbers are chosen.

Comment: Good effort! :)

Comment: Thanks for finding this!

Comment: Thanks, and you're welcome! I wrote a short Maple script to find minimal $3 \times 3$ examples whose eigenvalues *are* rational (which turns out, I think, to be a more interesting question) and updated my post with some data.

Comment: Once again I appreciate this a lot! I agree completely much more interesting than the latter. I'm currently looking for ones with one value rational the other two irrational with all non-zero elements. It is very interesting though as you said 252 of 9! cases because I was wondering just how rare these are.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm reasonably sure that for any $m$ if we randomly assign distinct elements of $\{0^2, \ldots, N^2\}$ to the entries of an $m \times m$ matrix that the probability of at least one root of the characteristic polynomial being rational goes to $0$ as $N \to \infty$. If you're familiar with Galois theory, there's a related result about the probability of a Galois group of a polynomial of fixed degree with integer coefficients is $S_n$ goes to $1$ as we exhaust the set of integer polynomials in certain reasonable ways.

Comment: By the way, if you have Maple, I'm happy to post my script (it's not well-optimized or anything) so that you can adapt it to other variants of these questions you're interested in.

Comment: Tweaking it just now, by the way, found the lexicographically first example (with entries $0^2, \ldots, 8^2$) $$\pmatrix{0^2&1^2&2^2\\4^2&6^2&8^2\\5^2&3^2&7^2},$$ which has rational eigenvalue $69$ and irrational eigenvalues $8 \pm 4 \sqrt{6}$.

Comment: I am not familiar with maple however I am well versed in programing in general so if it's not too much effort I'd love to play around with that. This is teaching me a lot. I am very interested in your comment above about the probability of at least one rational root going to zero. I'm not familiar with Galois theory but would be willing to take the time to learn and investigate this further. Is there a name for the result you mentioned? Do you know any good references for learning Galois theory (preferably undergraduate level)?

Comment: It was little trouble, I've added the code to my answer. I learned Galois Theory mostly from Dummit and Foote. I really like the exposition but it's a bit verbose for some tastes, I've heard.

Comment: By the way, my code found that $5064$ of the $9!$ matrices of the above form have precisely one rational root.

Comment: Thanks! I will be sure to play around with the maple script and read up on Galois theory. If you think of the name or come across a post on the result you mentioned above please let me know.

Comment: I've actually asked about it myself on this site: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939103/how-often-are-galois-groups-equal-to-s-n , where several other people gave helpful links. I wrote a partial answer in the question (a bad habit from an earlier time on the site, I do not recommend you emulate it) that gives the statement. I hesitated to post it above, since it probably doesn't make sense without knowing at least some Galois Theory first. AFAIK the result doesn't have a name, but a slogan version is "The Galois group of a random polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ is almost always $S_n$."

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion for anyone who comes across this later, there are many cases where eigenvalues are rational for $2x2$ matrices containing only distinct squared integers.The case were the eigenvalues are rational just appear less frequently. Looking at the radical from the question this becomes apparent:

$\sqrt{a^4+4b^2c^2-2a^2d^2+d^4}$

The reason they are not as easy to find is because in order for them to be rational, $a^4+4b^2c^2-2a^2d^2+d^4$ must be a squared number and this happens less frequently. The $3x3$ case has more or less the same explanation/result.